# Using jquery to use sum up the values of various Bootsrap switches (including multiplying some dropdown options)

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Here is simplified version of a shopping cart I'm attempting to create: I would like to add up the values of the switches, including multiplying by the value of the drop down selectors on switches that have them (e.g reampSwitch3 / Amp Simulator Matching).

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input reampingSwitch" id="reampSwitch1" value="20">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="reampSwitch1">Live Reamping Deposit</label>
</div>

        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input reampingSwitch" id="reampSwitch2" value="30">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="reampSwitch2">Another Service</label>
</div>

        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="reampSwitch3">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="reampSwitch3" value="10" >Amp simulator matching</label>


            <select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
    <option selected value="0">How Many Tracks?</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
    <option value="7">Seven</option>
    <option value="8">Eight</option>
    <option value="9">Nine</option>

  </select>
    </div>



        <div class="total" id="reampTotal">

      <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" id="reampSubtotal">
   Reamping Total : £0
</div>
      </div>
```

I have the following jQuery that can add up the switches without dropdowns, and display it in the reampSubtotal div. I can't figure out how to do the multiplications and add them in to the total:

```
   $(".reampingSwitch").click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".reampingSwitch:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });
         $("#reampSubtotal").html("Reamping Total : £" + (total));       


});
```

You can see a live version here:
http://www.recordingdoctor.com/Checkboxes.html

Comment: what exactly do you want to multiply? for an example if I select both the checkboxes (£50) and select two in the drop box, are you expecting  £100?

Comment: the value of the three switches need to add together. The first two switches have simple values, the third switch has a value that is determined by a multiplication of the drop down selection. That drop down has no effect on the value of the other switches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this. I took care for the situation that someone chooses a different amount of tracks after selecting another amount of tracks by adding a data-attribute `data-selected` to store the previous choice and substracting it from the total to prevent that different choices of tracks are being added to the total.

```js
$(".reampingSwitch").click(function() {
  let total = parseInt($("#reampSubtotal").text().replace("Reamping Total : £", ""));  
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
     total += parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
  }
  else if(!$(this).is(":checked")) {
     total -= parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
  };
  $("#reampSubtotal").html("Reamping Total : £" + (total));
});

$("#inlineFormCustomSelectPref").change(function() {
  if ($("#reampSwitch3").prop("checked") == true) {
    let selected = $(this).val();
    let price = selected * $("label[for='reampSwitch3']").attr("value");
    let total = parseInt($("#reampSubtotal").text().replace("Reamping Total : £", ""));
    if($(this).attr("data-selected")){
       let previous = $(this).attr("data-selected");
       let previousPrice = previous * $("label[for='reampSwitch3']").attr("value");
       total -= previousPrice;
    }
    total += price;
    $("#reampSubtotal").html("Reamping Total : £" + (total));
    $(this).attr("data-selected", selected);
  }
});
$("#reampSwitch3").click(function() {
  if ($("#inlineFormCustomSelectPref").val() > 0 && $(this).prop("checked") == true) {
       let selected = $("#inlineFormCustomSelectPref").val();
       let price = selected * $("label[for='reampSwitch3']").attr("value");
       let total = parseInt($("#reampSubtotal").text().replace("Reamping Total : £", ""));
       total += price;
       $("#reampSubtotal").html("Reamping Total : £" + (total));
  } 
  else if ($("#inlineFormCustomSelectPref").val() > 0 && $(this).prop("checked") == false) {
       let selected = $("#inlineFormCustomSelectPref").val();
       let price = selected * $("label[for='reampSwitch3']").attr("value");
       let total = parseInt($("#reampSubtotal").text().replace("Reamping Total : £", ""));
       total -= price;
       $("#reampSubtotal").html("Reamping Total : £" + (total));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input reampingSwitch" id="reampSwitch1" value="20">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="reampSwitch1">Live Reamping Deposit</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input reampingSwitch" id="reampSwitch2" value="30">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="reampSwitch2">Another Service</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="reampSwitch3">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="reampSwitch3" value="10">Amp simulator matching</label>


  <select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
    <option selected value="0">How Many Tracks?</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
    <option value="7">Seven</option>
    <option value="8">Eight</option>
    <option value="9">Nine</option>

  </select>
</div>



<div class="total" id="reampTotal">

  <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" id="reampSubtotal">
    Reamping Total : £0
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the input. However if I run the snippet, add an Amp simulator matching service first, and then add one of the other services, strange things start to happen with the displayed total.

Comment: @bill_face I fixed the issue. The problem was that total was set to 0 in the .reampingSwitch click function. Now the total is read from the #reampSubtotal text.

Comment: but now if you add a service on the first two switches and remove them they aren't subtracted

Comment: @bill_face Also noticed this and just fixed in my answer. It should work now as expected.

Comment: @bill_face Forget about my last comment, there still is an issue I'm about to take care now.

Comment: @bill_face Now it's working as intended. There was a problem with the each() function because a previously selected checkbox was added to the total again when the other checkbox got checked.

Comment: Brilliant. No however many times I toggle the check boxes like a lunatic, I can't get it to misbehave. Thanks so much.